# What is the rv parameter in the zend_read_property function

Tags: c, php-extension, zend-api

I'm using the zend_read_property to read the attribute from an object.

```
zend_read_property(
    scope: *mut zend_class_entry, 
    object: *mut zval, 
    name: *const c_char, 
    name_length: size_t, 
    silent: zend_bool, 
    rv: *mut zval
) -> *mut zval
```

```
zval *output, rv;

output = zend_read_property(ce, Z_OBJ_P(ZEND_THIS), ZEND_STRL("output"), ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_SILENT, &rv);
```

However, I don't know why it need the rv parameter.
What is the purpose of this parameter?

Comment: Typically, rv variable name is short for "return value", if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @TaimoorZaeem, no it isn't.
```zval *output, rv;
 output = zend_read_property(ce, Z_OBJ_P(ZEND_THIS), ZEND_STRL("output"), ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_SILENT, &rv);```

The *output is the return value. Not sure about the rv.

Answer (score 0):

The `rv` parameter is an easy way to give the class's `read_property` handler a place to store the property value (i.e. the return value). An implementation might not readily have the property value stored as a `zval`, in which case it can use the `rv` argument and let the caller worry about the lifecycle of the `zval`. You can think of it like a temporary location for the property value to live.

It's important to note that the `read_property` handler doesn't have to use the `rv` argument. Ideally, you should check to see if the return value equals the address of `rv`, in which case you should free the `rv` zval in case there is a dynamic memory structure associated with it (e.g. a string or object value).

Here's a blurb from [www.phpinternalsbook.com](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/classes_objects/object_handlers.html)

> read_property may directly return a zval owned by the object, in which case its reference count should not be modified by read_property, and the caller should not release it. Alternatively, it may return rv for temporary zvals (e.g. result of call to __get), in which case the refcount should be incremented, and the caller is responsible for releasing the value.

I've looked over some code from `php-src`, and I see many instances of calling `zend_read_property` that do not check/free the `zv` value as I would expect. It could be an optimization if the programmer knows that it won't ever be used by the handler in question.

It's also unclear to me whether the caller is responsible for initializing `rv`. I tend to think not: if the handler decides to use `rv`, it will ensure it is initialized and return its address. The caller should then, in the generic case, check if the return value equals `rv` and free it accordingly.